# Colors are wrong on my file?

Tags: rendering, texturing, color, error

I am new to blender, so my question might have a simple answer that I missed. Anyways, my issue is with rendered colors. I downloaded this model from online and the model is great, but the issue is with the colors of the model. I am using a model of Rouxls Kaard from Deltarune, but his hair and body pallets have inexplicably swapped themselves. To me, the texture file looks fine. But I can't figure out what's wrong. So if anyone can answer it, that'd be so awesome! [image: Rouxls Kaard Color Pallet is reversed]

[image: The texture I am using]